# PYQT6 installation on Windows 7 32-bit

Tags: pyqt6

This is the command line that I used to install

'(venv) C:\Windows\System32>pip install pyqt6'

```
Collecting pyqt6
Using cached PyQt6-6.2.2.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [29 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\hamza\arbah\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", 
  line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
  AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 
 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
 
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
     
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a 
problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please do not use all capitals, it is the internet equivalent of shouting, which is rude to do to people you want help from.

Comment: Windows 7 has left all kinds of (public available) security support two years ago. Are you sure you still want to use that?

Comment: i have no choice ,,,,

Comment: If you're using python 3.10, downgrade to python 3.9

Comment: I m using python 3.8

Comment: thank you but there is no version pyqt6 6.1 .3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyQt6 windows requirement:
Windows 10 (1809 or later)

Therefore, it does not work on Windows 7

source:
https://www.qt.io/product/qt6/technical-specifications